# Increment an Integer within a HashMap

Tags: java, pointers, reference, hashmap

Do I have to return the object and then put a new one in ? Or can I just directly increment ?

```
Integer temp = myMap.get(key);
temp++;
myMap.put(key, temp);
```

there is no way to just do this (this doesn't work) :

```
myMap.get(key)++;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Do I have to return the object and then put a new one in ?

As long as you use the `Integer` wrapper class yes, because it's immutable. You could use a mutable wrapper class instead, even one that has an `increment()` method. However, you then lose the ability to use autoboxing and autounboxing on the values.

Answer (score 34):

This is the shortest code that does this job.

```
myMap.put(key, myMap.get(key) + 1)
```

I think it is not too long.

Comment: How is it supposed to work? Put method takes 2 arguments, the key and new value.

Comment: +1 , IMO this should be the accepted answer : simple & concise - no need for immutable wrappers (placing Atomic constructs in non MT scenarios is *confusing*). As Piotr observed, the key should be the first arg though

Comment: Performance? 2 search operations: one with put() and one with get()

Comment: @IgriZdes, since OP stores immutable objects in Map there is not way to avoid double search. The only solution that allows to avoid this is using mutable objects with all advantages and disadvantages of this solution.

Comment: Note that this solution results in null pointer exceptions if values are not initialized for all possible keys.

Comment: This would solve the null pointer problem - simply wrap with an if - which allows adding a key if it doesn't exist and incrementing if it does...  if(myMap.containsKey(key)) {...}

Answer (score 30):

In Java 8 there are new methods on `Map` which you can use with lambdas to solve this. First alternative, [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
a.compute(key, (k, v) -> v+1);
```

Note that this only works if the hash is initialized for all possible keys.

If this is not guaranteed you can either change the above code to:

```
a.compute(key, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
```

Or use the [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method (which I would prefer):

```
a.merge(key, 1, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

Maybe there are more lambda based methods I am not aware of.

Comment: This is the best answer as per java8

Comment: FWIW if using Java 11 you can use a lambda function

    a.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);

Answer (score 21):

You can use a mutable integer such as AtomicInteger.

```
Map<Key, AtomicInteger> myMap = new HashMap<Key, AtomicInteger>();
myMap.get(key).incrementAndGet();
```

Or you can use Trove4j which supports primitives in collections.

```
TObjectIntHashMap<Key> myMap;
myMap.increment(key);
```

Comment: Question: when you say use incrementAndGet, you actually mean: `myMap.put(key, new AtomicLong(myMap.get(key).incrememtAndGet()));` right? To insert the new value in the map or incrementAndGet also updates the value in the map?

Comment: The map holds a reference, not the object itself. You don't need to put back a reference to mutable object in a map because you alter the underlying object not the reference.

Answer (score 7):

You can't directly increment it, because it is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). You have to increment it and put the new object back.

Auto boxing is also interfering here. In fact what's happening is something similar to:

```
Integer i1 = getFromMap();
i1 = Integer.valueOf(++ i1.intValue());
```

So here your reference points to a new object. You have to put that object back in the map, under the same key.

Answer (score 3):

As `Integer` are immutable, yes, you have to do it that way.
If you really want to increment it directly, you'll have to write your own mutable class.

Comment: Or use, say, `AtomicInteger`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to do this more than twice you'd prefer to create a tiny class like:

```
public class MappedCounter {

    private Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public void addInt(String k, int v) {
        if (!map.containsKey(k))    map.put(k, v);
        else                map.put(k, map.get(k) + v);
    }

    public int getInt(String k) {
        return map.containsKey(k) ? map.get(k) : 0;
    }

    public Set<String> getKeys() {
        return map.keySet();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Here are solutions using a `Map` (Java 8+), and a primitive `Map` and `Bag` using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/donraab/eclipse-collections) (EC).

**JDK `Map`**

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.merge("item", 1, Integer::sum);
Integer count = map.getOrDefault("item", 0);
```

**EC Primitive `Map`**

```
MutableObjectIntMap<String> map = ObjectIntMaps.mutable.empty();
map.addToValue("item", 1);
int count = map.getIfAbsent("item", 0);
```

**EC `Bag`**

```
MutableBag<String> bag = Bags.mutable.empty();
bag.add("item");
int count = bag.occurrencesOf("item");
```

The benefit of the primitive `Map` or `Bag` (which wraps a primitive Map) is that there is no boxing of the count values, and adding is explicit in both method names (`addToValue` / `add`). A `Bag` is a better data structure IMO if you want to simply count things.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: be aware of unboxing: the temp is from type Integer. But the operation ++ is implemented for int. So temp is unboxed to type int. This means if temp is null you run in a NullPointerException.

And you have to do it like you discripted in your first code block.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below code and it works but at the beginning you need to define a `BiFunction` describing that the operation is incrementing by 1.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> strInt = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> bi = (x,y) -> {
        if(x == null)
            return y;
        return x+y;
    };
    strInt.put("abc", 0);


    strInt.merge("abc", 1, bi);
    strInt.merge("abc", 1, bi);
    strInt.merge("abc", 1, bi);
    strInt.merge("abcd", 1, bi);

    System.out.println(strInt.get("abc"));
    System.out.println(strInt.get("abcd"));
}
```

output is

```
3
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness in Java 8 there is a longAdder which brings some benefits in comparison to AtomicInteger (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html)

```
final Map<WhatEver, LongAdder> result = new HashMap<>();
result.get(WhatEver).increment();
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
        // If the key you want to add does not exist then add it as a new key
        // And make the value 1
        if (map.get(key) == null) {
            map.put(key, 1);
        } else {
            // If the key does exist then replace the key's value with it's
            // Original value plus one
            map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
        }
```

Comment: Since the question is "can I directly increment an integer within a HashMap", I take it that your answer is essentially "no".

Comment: The question is -> "Increment an Integer within a HashMap"

Comment: The question is _"Do I have to return the object and then put a new one in? Or can I just directly increment?"_. I'm sorry you found my comment rude, but I consider it very unhelpful when answers don't address the question.

Answer (score -1):

Found this to be the best way, avoiding NPE.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(5, map.getOrDefault(5, 0) + 1);
System.out.println(map.get(5));

Output:
1
```